# C# Combobox populated with non-present items

Tags: c#, file, combobox

I have a combobox which is supposed to be populated from a text file when the form is opened, however regardless if the file is empty or not, the first item in the `ComboBox` is a random test item I made to try it out, and is not present in the file at all.
Here's the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string line;
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader("filepath");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
    }


    if (comboBox1.Items.Count == 0)
    {
      comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
      comboBox1.SelectedItem = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {

        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
        file.Close();

}
```

With the exception of the test item, the `ComboBox` get populated just fine, but I want to remove that test item. The "edit items" property of the `ComboBox` is completely empty, so it's not a default item and I am 100% certain the file path is correct. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Based on that code, it looks like you added the test item via the designer

Comment: You can check designer code if item were added there, check  `yourForm.Designer.cs` file. Or you can call `comboBox1.Items.Clear()` in the beginning of `Form1_Load` method, but it will be just workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to see where `comboBox1` is defined.

However, when you are reading from your file you are just adding to the existing items but not removing any that might already be there.

Add the line:

```
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
```

before you loop over the contents of the file. However, this is only a workaround and will mask the true source of the problem.

The other thing I'd do is check that you haven't read a blank line from the file:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Length > 0)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```

If you just added your test item in the designer then, unless you absolutely need to see it at design time, remove that initialisation.

Comment: This solved the issue, thanks. I'm still trying to figure out where that item is coming from, but at least this method works around it.

Comment: @Domz may be just a simple space or tab or newline in your file?

Comment: @Domz in your autogenerated designer file the designer populates any data used in the form designer, if the change isn't in your code then that's where it come from, if you clear out the control via the designer it should stop this happening but its a good idea to clear anything before you fill it

Comment: `comboBox1.Items.Clear();` is not a solution - it's workaround which delay problem for later time.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the combobox items before loading them.

You might have some defaults somewhere.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `DataBinding` for populatinig `ComboBox` with items

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("filepath"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }

    comboBox1.DataSource = lines;
}
```

But if your "test" item still remain somewhere in the code - it will be executed. So best solution is to find that and remove.

Just check all references for `comboBox1`. All changes made in designer will be generated as code in the `yourForm.Designer.cs` file.